# Unable to unmount mounted device, not found in mtab

Tags: mount

I have a usb drive (`/dev/sdb`) which is mounted in my system:

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sdb1 on /media/jviotti/CD8B-7D3E type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
...
```

However trying to unmount it from the terminal leads to the following error:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb -v
Could not find /dev/sdb in mtab
umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted
```

Can someone explain what is happening? How should I proceed to unmount the device from the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see `/dev/sdb1` is mounted at  `/media/jviotti/CD8B-7D3E`.

Try the command in a terminal: `sudo umount /dev/sdb1 -v`

`sdb` points your HDD and different partitions of HDD will be listed as different 'files'. In your case I guess there is only 1 partition i.e `sdb1`

Comment: It works in that case. Why can't I unmount `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sdb1`? Is there any explanation to that?

Comment: @jviotti `/dev/sdb1` is what was mounted, so it's what must be unmounted. That's the partition, while `/dev/sdb` is the whole drive. In *rare* cases a filesystem is written to a whole drive. Almost always a drive contains a partition table and a filesystem exists within a partition.